# multiple query with linq

Tags: c#, linq, multiple-tables

I hope someone can help me with the below.

My tables are like,

```
(Job)
JobID
CustomerID
JobPartID

Job -> JobPart (One to Many)
(JobPart)
JobPartID
JobID [Foreign Key – ref JobID(JobID)]
Pickup-AddressID [Foreign Key – ref Address(AddressID)]
Destination-AddressID [Foreign Key – ref Address(AddressID)]

Address is a separate table
(Address)
AddressID
HouseNo
Street
City
Etc..
```

What I want is, for a specific customer all the JobPart with the address details.

Answer (score 0):

Well that won't even compile as valid c#, but I think what you're looking for is something like this:

```
var results = 
    from j in job
    from jp in j.JobParts
    where j.CustomerID == 1
    select new { jp.PickupAddress, jp.DestinationAddress };
```

This will work assuming you've got proper navigation properties set up between `JobParts` and `Addresses`.

You can use this pretty easily as:

```
foreach(var record in results)
{
    var pickupHouseNo = record.PickupAddress.HouseNo;
    var pickupStreet = record.PickupAddress.Street;
    // ...
    var destinationHouseNo = record.DestinationAddress.HouseNo;
    var destinationStreet = record.DestinationAddress.Street;
    // do stuff
}
```

If you really want them as flat query results, just use this:

```
var results = 
    from j in job
    from jp in j.JobParts
    where j.CustomerID == 1
    select new 
    {
        PickupHouseNo = jp.PickupAddress.HouseNo, 
        PickupStreet = jp.PickupAddress.Street, 
        // ...
        DestinationHouseNo = jp.DestinationAddress.HouseNo , 
        DestinationStreet = jp.DestinationAddress.Street, 
    };
```

Comment: Thanks. I have edited my question. I think it was not clear. I have navigation properties set up. But I only want let say street and city from the address table. How do I achieve this. I am sorry if I am asking too simple or almost not difficult questions.

Comment: @Anup My original code allows you get any address properties you want, but if you want a flat query result, you can do that, too. See my updated answer.

Comment: I have tried this too. The problem here is jp.Address.Street works if (JobPart->Address) is a (One to Many). But here the foreign key is in JobPart. That means the other way is queryable which is (Address -> JobPart).